# What is middleware in Slim Framework?

Tags: middleware, slim

It says

> The Slim Framework implements a version of the Rack protocol. As a
>   result, a Slim application can have middleware that may inspect,
>   analyze, or modify the application environment, request, and response
>   before and/or after the Slim application is invoked.

which means "something" to me. Like, it makes something to some things. Like middle in nowhere. Also it states that it is implementation of [Rack protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rack_%28web_server_interface%29), something I have never heard in PHP.

Is there any practical use other than onions? What is the proper name of "middleware" in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Middlewares, in the Slim philosophy, is simply a sort of reusable and stacked hooks designed to alter the Slim environment progressively.

This is very useful - for example - when you need to authenticate an HTTP request, check if it is an AJAX request and log some data when a response is sent - this can be 3 separate middlewares.

The Rack protocol simply refers to the technology that inspired the author to build the Slim middlewares.